# Exterior Tensor Product and Fourier Mukai Transform.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider smooth projective $k$-varieties $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ and consider two kernels $\mathcal{P}_i\in D^b(X_i\times Y_i)$ and $\mathcal{P}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{P}_2\in D^b((X_1\times X_2)\times(Y_1\times Y_2))$. Then we want to prove that the induced fourier-mukai tranforms satiesfies $$\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{P}_2}(F^*\boxtimes G^*)\cong\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_1}(F^*)\boxtimes\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_2}(G^*)$$
where $F^*\in D^b(X_1),G^*\in D^b(X_2)$.

Consider:
$$ 
X_1\xleftarrow{\pi_1}X_1\times Y_1 \xleftarrow{p_2} X_1\times X_2\times Y_1\times Y_2\xrightarrow{q_2} X_2\times Y_2\xrightarrow{j}X_2
$$
with
$$
X_1\times X_2\times Y_1\times Y_2\xrightarrow{q_1}Y_1\times Y_2.
$$

Then we have (by some calculations):
$$\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_1}(F^*)\boxtimes\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_2}(G^*)
=(q_1)_*(p_2^*(\pi_1^*(F^*)\otimes\mathcal{P}_1))\otimes
(q_1)_*(q_2^*(j^*(G^*)\otimes\mathcal{P}_2))$$
and
$$\Phi_{\mathcal{P}_1\boxtimes\mathcal{P}_2}(F^*\boxtimes G^*)
=(q_1)_*(p_2^*(\pi_1^*(F^*)\otimes\mathcal{P}_1)\otimes q_2^*(j^*(G^*)\otimes\mathcal{P}_2)).$$
All of these are derived functors and I omitted 'R' and 'L'.

So the final of this is aim to prove this special case of derived pushforward can commute with derived tensor in derived category. Why?

Or using projection formula, we have to prove
$$Rq_*(A^*\otimes^LB^*)\cong Rq_*(A^*\otimes^LLq^*Rq_*B^*)$$
as quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Sasha I’m sorry, I don’t know how to prove the exterior tensor commute with fourier mukai transform. The final calculation of this is equivalent to prove that derived tensor commute with derived direct image in derived category.

Comment: Try to rewrite the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Sasha OK, I have rewritten it clearly.

Comment: There are more details now, but the question is till not clear to me.

Comment: @Sasha My question is why $\Phi_{P_1\boxtimes P_2}(F^*\boxtimes G^*)$ is quasi-isomorphic to $\Phi_{P_1}(F^*)\boxtimes\Phi_{P_2}(G^*)$. Thank you!